# Error in using postgres COPY in windows batch file

Tags: postgresql, csv, batch-file, psql, postgresql-9.3

This is working perfectly. All the columns in **table1** is successfully exported as a .csv file.

```
(
echo \copy table1 TO '%HOME%\net\CSV_OUTPUT.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
) | "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME%
```

But I wanted to export only selected columns to the .csv file but what I have tried so far does not work.

I have tried using SELECT but it returns an error that says "**TO was unexpected at this time**"

```
echo \copy (SELECT red_foo FROM table1) TO '%HOME%\net\CSV_OUTPUT.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I have also tried to remove the parentheses but it returns an error that says

"**\copy: parse error at "red_foo"**"

What should be the correct way for this implementation? Your suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Put the `\copy` statement into a separate SQL script and use `psql ... -f export.sql`

Comment: Or just escape the closing parenthesis.  `echo \copy (SELECT red_foo FROM table1^) TO etc...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this works perfectly. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion of @a_horse_with_no_name in the comments, I have successfully exported a .csv file with only selected columns.

A separate SQL script that contains the *\copy statement* is used on the psql command on my windows batch script and it works like a charm.